# Using direction of motion as a variable: What do do with undefined/infinite slopes?

Tags: missing-data, spatial, mean, circular-statistics

I have a list of x,y coordinates representing an object's motion through 2d space. I need to do statistics where I use the direction of motion (slope) as a covariate to my variable of interest. However, in some observation intervals, the object only moves on one axis, or doesn't move at all, resulting in either an undefined or infinite slope.

How should I deal with this for getting basic stats like average direction? Is it OK to simply replace the (infinite/-infinite) slopes where there was no motion on the x-axis with 1 or -1? Can the periods where there is no motion (resulting in NaN/undefined) be replaced with zero? Could I add the smallest number possible to all the zero values? Or would it be better to just drop the rows where the slope is zero/undefined?

Are "circular statistics" what I want to be reading about? Any tutorials dealing with this specific situation would be helpful.

Comment: I suggest you avoid conflating direction with slope.

Comment: So if understand correctly, atan2 is how I get direction, which is what I am actually interested in. I was thinking I could just use slope until I remembered in infinite/undefined slope issue.

Comment: Direction would presumably be an angle rather than a slope.

Comment: And atan2 gives that angle in radians, right?

Comment: If you only have the ratio of distances in the axis directions (i.e. slope), sure, but I was trying to suggest not even starting from there because you still have a problem when the denominator is 0.

Comment: No, I have both distances, so I think I'm good now.

Answer (score 2):

Yea, that's a real problem.

Spitballing, you could decompose your object's motion into the object's speed and the direction as measured by an angle (0 would be headed right in the x-y plane, $\pi/2$ would be headed up in the x-y plane, and so on).  Thus you would have two columns (speed and direction) which essentially give you information on the velocity.

Comment: I'm actually just looking at direction for the moment. So can I just use atan2(deltaY, deltaX)?